# what does the following Farm build version relate to (15 0 4641 1000)

Tags: 2013, installation, configuration, cumulative-update, farm

I have SharePoint server 2013 installed inside windows server 2008 r2. and i have updated the SharePoint server 2013 using windows update to use the latest CU.

so the final CU which i have installed is September 2014 CU and SP1.

now i run the following command:-

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> (get-spfarm).buildversion



Major  Minor  Build  Revision

-----  -----  -----  --------

15     0      4641   1000
```

but i can not find this version number inside the CU version on this [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2013/03/26/3561010.aspx)

so can anyone advice what does my current version relates to ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats from a blog, refer to microsoft technet for more uptodate version info:

**September 9, 2014 update for SharePoint Server 2013 (KB2889864)**

> This article describes update KB2889864 for Microsoft SharePoint
>   Server 2013 that was released on September 9, 2014.
>
> This update includes stability and performance improvements.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2889864

this build version is updating on the 12-Aug-2014 update that contains those files and carried on from 27-Jul-2014 update.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2760319

so that being said you can refer to this:

it shows you the latest builds for each area

http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn789211%28v=office.14%29

latest build is:

> This is build 15.0.4649.1001 of the cumulative update package

check manual way for verification on updates applied onto server:

central admin -> upgrade and migration -> check product and patch installation status

**EDIT**

ok i understand your frustration but if your updating correctly and that sharepoint is uptodate than there is no reason to be conserne. as i noted it could be several issues that could cause you to get the different build number:

to understand what is going on look into the powershell code your using:

```
(get-spfarm).buildversion
```

looking on msdn it states the following for the function `SPFarm.BuildVersion`:

> Gets the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation build version of the server
>   farm.

now read this as noted earlier:

> As a result of the packaging, it is no longer necessary to install the
>   SharePoint Foundation cumulative update and then install the
>   SharePoint Server cumulative update.

also like to note:

the powershell is looking up on build version not patch build version!

if you were to look into the kb for october you would see some items on old build and some on new builds. But the overall build from powershell is correct.

**EDIT**

Yes its important that you run wizard every time you do a CU,

I would:

1) install CU

2) reset server

3) run  SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard

4) reset server

5) check to make sure by running powershell code!

the  SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard will update the content database and configuration database with the update and apply any patches.

its very important to apply cu on all front end servers before you run  SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard!!!!

> Run the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard on the Central
>   Administration server (APP-1) to upgrade the configuration database
>   and upgrade each content database serially.

also note:

> Run the configuration wizard to ensure that if an update fails for a
>   specific server, the error is not propagated to the other web servers.
>   For example, a failed update for one server could make the update fail
>   for one or more site collections.

for a full setp guid from msdn on adding CU and updating with SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard then refer to this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806338%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: so you mean that i do not have September 2014 CU installed ? although i have a fix applied , where this fix was part of Septmber 2014  Cu...

Comment: i check the "check product and path installation status" and all the installation is either "Installed" or "Superseded", is this alright ?

Comment: yup that is fine! yes you do have september 2014 CU installed and all uptodate! within ca you should see what cu is installed and when with its version

Comment: what what is the differences between Superseded & Installed ?

Comment: Also One thing i noted is that i check my current "Manage Patch Status" inside system administrator , and it mentioned that "15.0.4649.1000" is installed... but for some reason the 

(get-spfarm).buildversion will shown 4641 instead of 4649 !!

Comment: can you advice please on my previous comments?

Comment: superseded is overwritten, installed is new or added. could be several reasons, could be that you need to reset server so powershell picksup new changes, could be that it wasnt a full update but a patch that occured so core files are still 4641 but patched files are 4649

Comment: so what do u recommend to do in this situation. as i mentioned before i have 4649 installed as per the "Patch status", but my get-spfarm.buildversion is saying that i got 4641 ?? so how i can fix this ,can u advice please?

Comment: did you run sharepoint Products Configuration Wizard after update? that is important to run

Comment: i would update again! there is a new update for October and it should put you at 15.0.4659.1001 CU and then run Products Configuration Wizard after update

Comment: yes on our Dev machine i install the October update yesterday and i run the configuration wizard, and it completed succfully, but still the get-spfarm.buildversion is saying that i got 4641, while on the "Patch status" i got 4657 ?? not sure what is the problem, or if i even have a problem or not?

Comment: just updated my answer

Comment: thanks for the help, so in this case i have Septemver 2014 CU installed successfully ? is this correct ?

Comment: yes you have september cu installed!

Comment: no problem happy to help! its confusing untill you dig into the method in how its getting that value and what type of cu you have installed. Dont worry you have the latest CU installed!

Comment: OK now i install the October 2014 CU using windows update today. Then i run the Configuration Wizard, but it raise a timeout error, however when i check the CA "Patch Status", i saw that the CU 4657 is installed, so is running the configuration wizard mandatory for October 2014 CU ?

Comment: ok, its important you follow my last update! its important that you run SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard on any CU you install and you must install CU on all front end servers before running SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard

Comment: thanks a lot for the great help, but when i finish runing the configuration wizard, it never mentioned that i should restart the server (unlike installing CU which ask to restart the server). but what did u mean by "check to make sure by running powershell code!",, which powershell code i should use ?

Comment: no restarting the server before you run the configuration, so install cu, restart server, run config wizard.... ps code is the code you used in your question for the last step for confirmation: (get-spfarm).buildversion

Answer (score 1):

The Build version you mentioned in your question is for August 2014 CU.

But as you said you installed the Spetember 2014 CU then your version should be `15.0.4649.1000`.

As you mentioned in the post, two things make sure( both are mandatory.

- Install the [September 2014 CU](http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;2883068) on all servers in the farm.
- Run the Config wizard on all server in the farm. If you did not run the config wizard then SharePoint will show last build number.
- Lastly run the Get-SPproduct -Local to update the config db.

Comment: but when i check the "Manage Patch Status" inside the system administrator,it mentioned that the 15.0.4649.1000 is already installed , , and i successfully run the Config wizard... but (get-spfarm).buildversion will shown 4641 instead of 4649.. can u advice please?

Comment: and i only have one SharePoint server. i do not want to be doing unnecessary steps. i am sure that September 2014 CU was part of the WU i did one month ago, also today i Run a windows update and it mentioned that i have SharePoint October 2014 CU (but i did not installed till now). and also inside the "Patch status" on my CA it mentioned that 4649 is installed ....

Comment: Did you try to download the spet 2014 current directly from site n try to install it?also make sure you download the server patch not foundation

Comment: but inside the "Central administration>>upgrade and migration>>check product and patch status" section, it mentioned that i have 15.0.4649.1000 installed,, so why i need to download it again? also the recommended approach to install SharePoint 2013 CU is using windows update tool, this is Microsoft instruction not mine...

Comment: I m not arguing on msft recommendation but as of now you have issue then why not try to to direct install...as per my little experience we never apply cu as part of WU....we always patch server separately n SharePoint separately in order to easy troubleshooting if any issue.

Comment: did you run this command on the server: Get-SPproduct -Local

Comment: also if the CU already installed and you trying to install again it will give the message already installed.

Comment: thanks for the reply , but i am affraid that if i install the CU manully either i will face some errors, or i will not get anything different.so i want to make sure that there is not anyway to fix this according to my current situation.. thnaks