# Unable to get all my SharePoint 2013 CUs installed, using windows update tool

Tags: 2013, administration, configuration-wizard, patching

I am facing problems in applying September and October 2014 CUs using windows update. I have the following:-

1. SharePoint server 2013 SP1.
2. Windows server 2008 r2.

I use to have SharePoint 2013 since it being RTM. And I use to update my SharePoint server and applying different SharePoint CU using windows update.

Today for example I got the following using windows update, which include October 2014 CU:-

[image]

So I install all the updates, restart the server, then I run the configuration wizard and everything went find.

But I run the following command inside my sharepoint server , I got the following:-

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> (get-spfarm).buildversion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
15     0      4641   1000
```

Where (4641) means that I still have August 2014 CU and not October 2014, although windows update include the October CU and the config wizard worked successfully.
However when I check the Central administration>>upgrade and migration>>check product and patch status, I found that I have September CU and October CU installed,, but this is not reflected inside (get-spfarm).buildversion as follow:-

[image]

So I am totally confused about my current situation and if I am missing any of the CUs?
Can anyone advice please?
Thanks

**EDIT**
here is the log error when i run the following command   `PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures`

```
 Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  ERR            Task upgrade has failed with a PostSetupConfigurationTaskException An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The upgrade command is invalid or a failure has been encountered.
Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF            Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                  Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                  Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information: {1}
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF            Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  ERR            An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The upgrade command is invalid or a failure has been encountered.
Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF            Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                  Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                  Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information: {1}
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF            Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF            Entering function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                Found value in collection for key global
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              Found command global in collection
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF            Leaving function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF            Entering function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                Found value in collection for key initialize
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              Found command initialize in collection
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF            Leaving function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF            Entering function Command.this[string key]
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                Found value in collection for key SINGLESERVER
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              Found parameter SINGLESERVER in collection
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF            Leaving function Command.this[string key]
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF            Entering function Command.this[string key]
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                Found value in collection for key upgradesessionid
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              Found parameter upgradesessionid in collection
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF            Leaving function Command.this[string key]
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF            Releasing the farm upgrade lock in common exception handler.
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF            Entering function UpgradeBootstrapTask.BuildUpgradeExtendedMessage
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              Task result is fail
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF            Leaving function UpgradeBootstrapTask.BuildUpgradeExtendedMessage
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF            Entering function TaskBase.OnTaskStop
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              Creating the OnTaskStop event for task upgrade
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  ERR              Task upgrade has failed
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              friendlyMessage for task upgrade is An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The upgrade command is invalid or a failure has been encountered.
Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              debugMessage for task upgrade is An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The upgrade command is invalid or a failure has been encountered.
Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF              Entering function TaskBase.FireTaskStateChanged
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                Firing the OnTaskStateChanged event for task upgrade
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                Entering function TaskDriver.TaskStateEventHandler
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                  Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                    Resource id to be retrieved is UpgradeTaskDisplayName for language English (United States)
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                    Resource retrieved id UpgradeTaskDisplayName is upgrade SharePoint Products
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                  Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                  Received an TaskStateEventHandler event.  task:upgrade TaskBase.State:stopped
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                  Entering function TasksQueue.IncrementTaskFailed
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                    Incremented the number of tasks failed to 1
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                  Leaving function TasksQueue.IncrementTaskFailed
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                  Task upgrade has stopped and failed.  Total failed is now 1
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                Leaving function TaskDriver.TaskStateEventHandler
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                Entering function CommandLine.TaskStateEventHandler
10/16/2014 16:56:30  16  INF                  Received an TaskStateEventHandler event.  task:upgrade TaskBase.State:stopped
```

**EDIT2**

I got the following error when i run the power shell command:-

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures
```

[image]

And here is the related logs, as i find multiple exceptions:-

```
Resource retrieved id ServiceConnectionPointNotCreatedEventLog is Unable to create a Service Connection Point in the current Active Directory domain. Verify that the SharePoint container exists in the current domain and that you have rights to write to it.
10/17/2014 11:32:07  15  INF            Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
10/17/2014 11:32:07  15  WRN            Unable to create a Service Connection Point in the current Active Directory domain. Verify that the SharePoint container exists in the current domain and that you have rights to write to it.
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The object LDAP://CN=Microsoft SharePoint Products,CN=System,DC=ad-Tgroup,DC=intra doesn't exist in the directory.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceConnectionPoint.Ensure(String serviceBindingInformation)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
10/17/2014 11:32:27  15  INF            Entering function TaskCommon.TraceToPsconfigLogAndUpgradeManagerLog
10/17/2014 11:32:27  15  INF              Spawning off the upgrade job
10/17/2014 11:32:27  15  INF            Leaving function TaskCommon.TraceToPsconfigLogAndUpgradeManagerLog
10/17/2014 11:32:27  15  INF            Trying to start the SPAdminV4 service
10/17/2014 11:32:27  15  INF            Entering function ServiceHelper.TryToStartService
10/17/2014 11:32:27  15  INF              Trying to start the SPAdminV4 service
10/17/2014 11:32:27  15  INF              Entering function ServiceHelper.Start
10/17/2014 11:32:27  15  INF                Trying to start service SPAdminV4 and waiting 180 sec to do so
10/17/2014 11:32:27  15  INF                service SPAdminV4 is Stopped, will try to start it
10/17/2014 11:32:27  15  INF                starting service SPAdminV4 (it may already be started)
10/17/2014 11:32:27  15  INF              Leaving function ServiceHelper.Start
10/17/2014 11:32:27  15  INF            Leaving function ServiceHelper.TryToStartService
10/17/2014 11:32:27  15  INF            Entering function TaskCommon.TraceToPsconfigLogAndUpgradeManagerLog
10/17/2014 11:32:27  15  INF              Yielding psconfig session on current thread to allow the admin service to run upgrade in the background.
10/17/2014 11:32:27  15  INF            Leaving function TaskCommon.TraceToPsconfigLogAndUpgradeManagerLog
10/17/2014 11:32:38  15  INF            Starting all registered services
10/17/2014 11:32:38  15  INF            Entering function UpgradeTask.StartAllServices
10/17/2014 11:32:38  15  INF              Entering function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
10/17/2014 11:32:38  15  INF                Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/17/2014 11:32:38  15  INF                  Found value in collection for key initialize
10/17/2014 11:32:38  15  INF                Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/17/2014 11:32:38  15  INF                Found command initialize in collection
10/17/2014 11:32:38  15  INF              Leaving function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
10/17/2014 11:32:38  15  INF              Entering function Command.this[string key]
10/17/2014 11:32:38  15  INF                Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/17/2014 11:32:38  15  INF                  Found value in collection for key B2B_UPGRADE
10/17/2014 11:32:38  15  INF                Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/17/2014 11:32:38  15  INF                Found parameter B2B_UPGRADE in collection
10/17/2014 11:32:38  15  INF              Leaving function Command.this[string key]
10/17/2014 11:32:38  15  INF              Starting Service SearchRuntimeServiceInstance
10/17/2014 11:32:38  15  INF              Detected that this is a build to build upgrade. Re-provision the SearchRuntimeServiceInstance service
10/17/2014 11:32:59  15  INF              Starting Service SPWindowsTokenServiceInstance
10/17/2014 11:32:59  15  INF              Detected that this is a build to build upgrade. Re-provision the SPWindowsTokenServiceInstance service
10/17/2014 11:33:25  15  INF              Starting Service SPTracingServiceInstance
10/17/2014 11:33:25  15  INF              Detected that this is a build to build upgrade. Re-provision the SPTracingServiceInstance service
10/17/2014 11:33:44  15  INF              Starting Service SPUserCodeServiceInstance
10/17/2014 11:33:44  15  INF              Detected that this is a build to build upgrade. Re-provision the SPUserCodeServiceInstance service
10/17/2014 11:33:56  15  INF              Starting Service SearchServiceInstance
10/17/2014 11:33:56  15  INF              Detected that this is a build to build upgrade. Re-provision the SearchServiceInstance service
10/17/2014 11:35:08  15  INF              Starting Service LauncherServiceInstance
10/17/2014 11:35:08  15  INF              Detected that this is a build to build upgrade. Re-provision the LauncherServiceInstance service
10/17/2014 11:35:12  15  INF              Starting Service SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
10/17/2014 11:35:12  15  INF              Detected that this is a build to build upgrade. Re-provision the SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance service
10/17/2014 11:35:15  15  INF            Leaving function UpgradeTask.StartAllServices
10/17/2014 11:35:15  15  INF            SyncUpgradeTimerJob: sleeping for 10 seconds
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            SyncUpgradeTimerJob: SPTIMERV4 is not running anymore. Return -1.
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  ERR            The exclusive inplace upgrader timer job failed.
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString


/// Also i found these exceptions
Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Resource id to be retrieved is InvalidCommandOrCommandFailed for language English (United States)
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Resource retrieved id InvalidCommandOrCommandFailed is The {0} command is invalid or a failure has been encountered.
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF                Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF                Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information: {1}
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  ERR            Task upgrade has failed with a PostSetupConfigurationTaskException An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The upgrade command is invalid or a failure has been encountered.
Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF                Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF                  Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF                  Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information: {1}
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF                Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  ERR            An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The upgrade command is invalid or a failure has been encountered.
Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF                Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF                  Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF                  Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information: {1}
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF                Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Entering function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF                Found value in collection for key global
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Found command global in collection
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Leaving function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Entering function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF                Found value in collection for key initialize
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Found command initialize in collection
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Leaving function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Entering function Command.this[string key]
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF                Found value in collection for key SINGLESERVER
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Found parameter SINGLESERVER in collection
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Leaving function Command.this[string key]
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Entering function Command.this[string key]
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF                Found value in collection for key upgradesessionid
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Found parameter upgradesessionid in collection
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Leaving function Command.this[string key]
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Releasing the farm upgrade lock in common exception handler.
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Entering function UpgradeBootstrapTask.BuildUpgradeExtendedMessage
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Task result is fail
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Leaving function UpgradeBootstrapTask.BuildUpgradeExtendedMessage
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF            Entering function TaskBase.OnTaskStop
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Creating the OnTaskStop event for task upgrade
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  ERR              Task upgrade has failed
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              friendlyMessage for task upgrade is An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The upgrade command is invalid or a failure has been encountered.
Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              debugMessage for task upgrade is An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The upgrade command is invalid or a failure has been encountered.
Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
10/17/2014 11:35:25  15  INF              Entering function TaskBase.FireTaskStateChanged
```

Comment: Dude how your this question is different than old one, please dont create duplicate the questions, if you want attention then start the bounty on your question so more people will respond.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does the following Farm build version relate to (15 0 4641 1000)](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118175/what-does-the-following-farm-build-version-relate-to-15-0-4641-1000)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

1. clear configuration cache
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamesway/archive/2011/05/23/sharepoint-2010-clearing-the-configuration-cache.aspx
2. Find current pv value using:
   `stsadm -o getproperty -pn command-line-upgrade-running`
   if -pv value is yes, change to No. If no change to Yes

   `stsadm -o setproperty -pn command-line-upgrade-running -pv No`
3. re-run configuration wizard:

   ```
     PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures
   ```
4. If still not working, it might need server reboot

Reference link:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/balasm/archive/2012/05/18/configuration-wizard-failed-an-update-conflict-has-occurred-and-you-must-re-try-this-action.aspx

Comment: can u please advice what will be the differences between running the configuration wizard from the UI , and running the power shell command u provide ?

Comment: @robert can you check my edit to the original question, as i got an error when i run the power-shell command which u mentioned.. can u advice , thanks?

Comment: @johnGm I have not answered this question

Comment: @JohnG: It is the same running using configuration wizard. but please clear the configuration cache first.

Comment: @johnG: I have update my answer. I hope it resolve your issue

Comment: @Supermode can you check my "Edit2" section inside my original question, as i could not run the configuration wizard and it return some exceptions.. can u advice please?